# Add a header row to a bed file in Cygwin

Tags: header, cygwin, cat

I have a bed file of three columns, and I would like to add the following headers: (chr \t start \t stop). I tried using the following command

```
echo -e "chr\tstart\tstop" | cat - myfile.bed > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out myfile.bed
```

But every time I run this I get the follwoing error: *cat: myfile.bed: No such file or directory*
Although I'm sure the file is in that directory with the same name.

What edits I can make to let this work? or if you know another way of adding a header to a tab delimited bed file, please suggest.

Comment: Does it work without `&& mv /tmp/out myfile.bed` ?

Comment: No, it shows the same error

Comment: than you are not in the same directory than `myfile.bed` or you are mistyping something